# Building a wah-wah pedal

Tags: gears

I want to prototype a wah-wah guitar pedal using an arduino, a potentiometer, and some meccano I have lying around.
I thought of two ways to do this :

the first one is to put a pinion on the pot, and connect a rack to the pedal itself; however I can already see that it can't be as simple as that, because the rack to pinion angle will change as the pedal gets pushed more.

the second one is to use several gears, the first one on the axle of the pedal, the last one on the potentiometer, so that the full motion of the pedal results in a full potentiometer rotation; I don't like that one much, as I don't think I have the requisite gear ratios.

Having absolutely no background in mechanics, that's it for me; I don't even know the name of the concepts I might be needing. Can Stackexchange Engineering provide some pointers for making this at home, with no complex tools beyond a sander, a dremel, and such?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a potentiometer is a bad idea in the long term, because typical electronic pots are not designed to handle high mechanical loading or very frequent movement. Compare how may times in a day (or even in a minute) you are likely to operate the pedal, compared with how many times you adjust the volume pot on a radio or a similar device.

A better idea would be to make a "contact-free" mechanism that outputs the position of the pedal. One effective home-built solution is to use an analog optical system. All you need is a light source (e.g. an LED) and a photodiode, separated by a moving vane with a variable-width slot in it to vary the amount of light that reaches the photodiode as you move the pedal. Write some software for the Arduino to convert the photodiode output into whatever you need to control the sound generation part of the project.

This doesn't require a complicated mechanical design. The moving vane can be fixed directly onto the pedal itself.

This type of system was used for the various control pedals on pipe organs long before digital electronics was available - often with a small light bulb powered at well below its rated voltage to increase its life span, and a "photocell" similar to those used in pre-electronic photographic light meters as the sensor. They worked reliably for decades, with no maintenance whatever.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the interesting history lesson. I might just try that!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but an Arduino should be capable of interpreting pulse train or positional transducers. These are used in industrial machines so are really rugged. This would allow the software to map the signal onto all sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have a toothed pulley connected to the pot and have a toothed belt wrapped around it at about 90 degrees held in tension by a spring. So that it comes down vertically from the footplate of the pedal and then wraps around the pulley to the horizontal plane to be joined to the back of the base of the pedal.

As mentioned in another answer more modern pedals which directly control some parameter eg wah/volume/pitch often use optical sensors as they are more durable and less likely to introduce noise.

Comment: The mechanical design problem with this idea is that most electronic components sold as "potentiometers" don't have internal bearings for the rotor that can withstand any significant side loads. You would really need to put a "proper" mechanical bearing onto the pot shaft to counteract the side loads when the spring is in tension, and then just prevent the body of the pot from rotating without creating any unwanted mechanical loads inside the pot itself.